# How to have multiple host names for azure website

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created an web app for a demo website in Azure.  The domain name for this website was created when I created the app service "myapp1.azurewebsites.net".  I'd like to use additional domain names using the same azurewebsites.net such as myapp2.azurewebsites.net.  When I try to add this custom domain it tells me

> Failed to add hostname myapp2.azurewebsites.net. Too many (2)
>   hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1

Is there no way around this or must I use my own custom DNS name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to add **[custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)** in Azure web app.

For example : when I created the app service "myapp1.azurewebsites.net" and want to have additional domain names , you can go for custom domains like abc.com.

You can not have .azurewebsites.net as the custom domain of already existing web app as it is already owned by Microsoft Azure web app.